# Function with animate() displays strange flicker in IE using show/hide

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, show-hide

I've created a little ribbon that slides open and closes with a click on my page. When I view the ribbon animation in IE7 on XP Pro everything works great until the end of the 'hide' part of the function.

The 'hide' part of the function slides up the element to be hidden and, just as it's completed hiding, the element flashes on the page and then goes away again.

Is there something in the following code that would cause this behavior that I'm not aware of?

Also, here's a fiddle (which works fine in all other browsers)... [Slider ribbon jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VyEBV/1/)

Here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.extender').animate({
            height: 'hide'
        }, 20);
    $('.special_offers_ribbon_showmore').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
    });
    $('.special_offers_ribbon_showmore').click(function(){
        if ($('.extender').hasClass('extended')) {
            $('.extender').animate({
            height: 'hide'
        }, 500, function(){
            $('.extender').removeClass('extended');
            $('.hidedetails').hide();
            $('.showdetails').show();
        });
        } else {
        $('.extender').animate({
            height: 'show'
        }, 200, function(){
            $('.extender').addClass('extended');
            $('.hidedetails').show();
            $('.showdetails').hide();

        });
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT** Per the comments, I tried going with the `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` and I'm still getting the flicker right at the end of the `slideUp()` function. Here's that scrips (which I like much more - seems cleaner...):

```
$('.special_offers_ribbon_showmore').hover(

function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
});
$('.special_offers_ribbon_showmore').click(function() {
    if ($('.extender').is(':hidden')) {
        $('.extender').slideDown(
            'slow', 
            function() {
            $('.hidedetails').show();
            $('.showdetails').hide();
        });
    } else {
        $('.extender').slideUp(
            'slow',
            function() {
            $('.hidedetails').hide();
            $('.showdetails').show();

        });
    }
});​
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="special_offers_ribbon">
<div id="special_offers_ribbon_detail" class="extender">
<img src="../images/ribbon_top.png">
<h1>Book a new meeting for 2012 and save!</h1>
<p>Free meeting space</p>
<p>No set-up fee</p>
<p>Free A/V Packages</p>
<p>&hellip; and much more!</p>
<a href="../events/index.cfm" title="See a full list of the 2012 Meetings and Events special offers here."><img src="../images/learn_more.png"></a>
                                            </div>
 <div id="special_offers_ribbon_opener">
 <img src="../images/ribbon_top.png">
 <h1 class="opener_headline">2012</h1>
 <p class="opener_text">Meetings &amp; Events<br />Special Offers<br /><span class="showdetails special_offers_ribbon_showmore"><img src="../images/showdetails.png" title="Show Details"></span><span class="hidedetails special_offers_ribbon_showmore"><img src="../images/hidedetails.png" title="Hide Details"></span></p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

And, the CSS:

```
p.ribbon_room {
    padding:0 210px 0 0;
}
#special_offers_ribbon {
    width:267px;
    float:right;
    padding:0px 0px 110px 0px;
    margin:0px 0px;
    background:transparent url(../images/ribbon.png) bottom center no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
}
#special_offers_ribbon h1 {
    margin:1px 50px 0 50px;
    padding:10px 0 0 0;
    border-top:1px dotted #eee7c6;
    color:#eee7c6;
}
#special_offers_ribbon p {
    margin:0 50px 0 50px;
    padding:0;
    color:#eee7c6;
}
#special_offers_ribbon p span.hidedetails {
    display:none;
}
#special_offers_ribbon div#special_offers_ribbon_detail a img{
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried slideToggle or slideUp/slideDown? May be worth checking to see if that helps.

Comment: @MoinZaman I've updated the jsFiddle with slideUp/slideDown. Still have the same problem. http://jsfiddle.net/VyEBV/3/

Comment: A simple SO search for "slideup flicker" yields the most probable solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821306/jquery-flicker-on-slideup-in-all-browsers-sample-page-attached

Comment: @vzwick There's no change in the behavior after implementing the aforementioned fix. Thank you for providing me some input though. I'll be careful to look deeper in the archives before posting.

Comment: I'll take another look at your question tomorrow – I recall stumbling upon similar issues some time ago.

Comment: @vzwick It's only a single flicker of the full `<div>` being hidden at the very end of the slideUp, which is strange. Everything else animates smoothly and works like a charm.

Comment: Is the ribbon at the very top of the viewport?

Comment: Did you ever solve the issue?

Comment: When I applied the `overflow:hidden` it did not fix the issue on the site. Although, when I applied it to the Fiddle, it did. So, the issue I believe my be with something else on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just worked around your issue by:

- setting the `#special_offers_ribbon` element's `position` to `relative` and `top` to `-210px`
- animating the `top` instead of the `height` property.

It's not pretty – yet it works, as long as your element sits at the top of the viewport of inside a container with `overflow:hidden` applied.

[Working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VyEBV/4/)

Comment: This solution worked for the element when it was taken out of the document flow. Unfortunately, the element with the problem needs to remain in the flow of the document which leads me to believe there's something else on the page that's contributing to the problem and will need more investigation.